# Modx: getResources filtered by TV

Tags: filter, modx, getresource, modx-revolution

I have a TV "Tags", comma separated… the usual stuff. Now I want to show only resources with a specific TV:

```
<ul class="resource-by-tag">
  [[!getResources? &parents=`15` &tpl=`resourceByTagRow` &includeTVs=`1` &processTVs=`1` &tvFilter=`tags==rundfunk` &tvPrefix=``]]
</ul>
```

As you might guess this doesn't work… but why? It shows *all* resources no matter what.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was just a typo:

```
[[!getResources? &parents=`15` &tpl=`resourceByTagRow` &includeTVs=`1` &processTVs=`1` &tvFilters=`tags==rundfunk` &tvPrefix=``]]
```

Works as expected. It must be `tvFilters` instead of `tvFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that it may have something to do with `&tvFilter='tags==rundfunk'` and tags looking something like this `ahfunk, beefunk, redfunk` the tag would include `redfunk` but would not `==redfunk`

have you tried using `where`? I only see it with the = clause, but you might have more choice there.